# parse.com - query by highest values?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a Photo class and one of it's fields is commentsCount, a number. I want to query the Photo class to return the photos with the most comments. If I have a small number of photo objects, then I just query for them and orderByDescending.

However, I haven't been able to test this with a large number of objects.

- Does orderByDescending sort only the returnedObjects?
- Or does it sort all the objects in the database and return topmost results?

If it only sorts the returnedObjects, how can I write a Parse query to return the topmost results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--data-urlencode 'order=-commentsCount'
--data-urlencode 'limit=20'
--data-urlencode 'skip=0'
```

Above will get you page 1 ( starts with highest value )

Below will page to the next 20 highest values ( page 2 )

```
--data-urlencode 'order=-commentsCount'
--data-urlencode 'limit=20'
--data-urlencode 'skip=20'
```

Above  from RestAPI manual(Queries section).

Note the minus sign in order parm value.

Comment: So your saying that if I limit to, say, 20, and there are thousands of entries in the database, then it will return the highest 20 from the entire DB? That's the heart of my question.